# http://localhost:50070 shows unable to connect but http://localhost:50030 is working

Tags: hadoop

I'm using Vmware with centos version 6(Fedora). I'm using hadoop version 1.0.4. My **`http://localhost:50070`** address shows "unable to connect", but the **`http://localhost:50030`** address is working.

My `jps` command is showing this:

```
5296 SecondaryNameNode
5697 Jps
5171 DataNode
5382 JobTracker
5514 TaskTracker.
```

Comment: I would start asking: why are you using such an old version of hadoop? If you can use one of the latest it would be better.

Comment: Similarly, why an old version of Centos?

Answer (score 0):

Port 50070 is related to the HDFS service and it corresponds to the described behaviour because the NameNode is not running (according to the `jps` command). Most probably you have a configuration issue in the hdfs xml configuration files. To find why the NameNode was not able to start, please go to the hadoop NameNode logs (`$HADOOP_HOME/logs`) and trace the error, commonly specified in the clause Caused By.